# Counter won't appear on my app. Not sure why?

Tags: java, android, time

I'm quite new to android and have recently been using tutorials to build games. The current game I'm trying to build is a maze.

The maze is created in a class called 'GameView' which extends 'View'.I have asked recently for help creating a Counter that counts upwards but had no success in implementing anything that was suggested. So I turned to creating my own method/code.

I keep having my app crashing when trying to put a method in any of the 'GameView' methods, so I put my Counter method in the 'OnCreate' method inside the MainAcivity class. My code is shown below of how I tried to implement a counter, and although having it in the MainActivity helps stop the app from crashing, the counter wont show up.

I've tried using stopwatch(with no success, I'm not sure of how to use this).

I've used Chronometer(again, no success).

I've used a CounterDownTimer, and although I got it to display a counter and got it to count upwards, unfortunately I couldn't get the timer to stop when the maze was finished by the user... it would only stop when it reach the millisUntilFinished variable.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        while(!isInterrupted()){
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                TextView textViewTime = findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
                                long seconds = 0;
                                long minutes = 0;
                                seconds += 1;
                                if (seconds >= 60) {
                                    minutes = seconds / 60;
                                    seconds = seconds % 60;
                                    textViewTime.setText("Time: " + df.format(minutes) + ":" + df.format(seconds));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
```

My code wont display on my app. Please help!

Comment: "I've used Chronometer(again, no success)." - What was wrong with it? It should fit your requirements perfectly.

Comment: Lack of understanding of how its used probably. All guides on how its used require buttons to start/stop or pause it.

Comment: The `Runnable` code in `runOnUiThread`  runs once (per outer loop iteration) and sets seconds,minutes to 0, so it never satisfies `seconds >= 60`.  You need to put `seconds` and `minutes` outside the scope of the `Runnable` so it persists.

Comment: If I remove the textview, the seconds +=1 to below Thread.sleep it doesn't seem to make a difference?